# resharper intellisense problem with extension methods

Tags: extension-methods, resharper, intellisense

so, I have a repository defined with a method like this:

```
IQueryable<Customer> Customers{...}
```

and elsewhere an extension method to filter the customers like so:

```
public static IQueryable<Customer> WithID(this IQueryable<Customer> customers, int ID){...}
```

and this woks nicely, letting me use the repository like this:

```
var c = repo.Customers().WithID(5).Single();
```

but the problem is, ReSharper messes up the Auto-Completion on this big time.  When I type

```
var c = repo.Customers().Wi
```

I get nice Intellisense showing me the WithID(...) method, but when I cursor down to it and hit TAB, instead of getting the WithID() method as expected, it goes back and changes code already written and the line ends up looking instead like:

```
var c = CustomerExtensions.WithID(repo.Customers())
```

which of course leaves me having to go back and type it in again, and this time IGNORE intellisense - which IMHO is NEVER a good thing :)

I have confirmed that it is a ReSharper problem by going into options and specifying "Visual Studio" for Intellisense.  I don't want to go back to plain Studio!

Can anyone help or suggest a workaround?

Comment: I don't have that problem with any of our extension methods. What version of ReSharper are you using?

Comment: R# 5.1 VS 2010, Windows 7.  Class Library project in framework 4.0.  Hmmm.. this happens to all of our developers here, not just me.

Comment: Did you find a solution? This happens to me aswell in a number of situations.

Comment: Sorry MatteS - this still happens, it almost makes using extension methods in this context not worth it.

Comment: I'm getting this with Enumerable.Concat and Resharper 8.1, VS 2013. It's so incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 5):

This was affecting me as well. Looks like it's a known bug:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-274746

Turning off Resharper -> Options -> IntelliSense -> Completion Behaviour -> "Automatically insert parentheses after completion" helps.

Comment: That removes the bug for me, although not the best solution to the problem really. Looks like the bug was fixed in 6.0, but it's back in 8. Seems like they have fixed it again in 9.0, so you only need to pay a few hundred dollars (again) to fix the issue. 9.0 seems to still struggle with the extension methods, but rather than changing the invocation, it just doesn't open the parentheses at all, and pulls up the next line instead. What is it they say about developers writing bugs to keep themselves employed? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-426530

Comment: Turning that setting off and on again seems to have fixed it for mr

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke it as an extension method by using type completion (CTRL + ALT + SPACE) and this will bypass the bug correctly.

This bug only happens for certain extension methods, don't know why though.