# Session not saved in ServiceStack

Tags: session, servicestack

I want to use the session feature but without athentication.
I already added `Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature())` to `AppHost.cs` and I have the following code

```
public class CustomService : Service
{
public CustomResponse Any(CustomRequest pRequest)
{
    var CustomSession = base.Session.Get<CustomType>("MySession");//try to get the session
    if (CustomSession == null)
    {
        //create a new session
        CustomSession = new CustomType{MyId=1};
        base.Session["MySession"] = CustomSession;
        //base.Session.Set("MySession", CustomSession); //also tried this, to save the session.
        this.SaveSession(CustomSession,  new TimeSpan (0,20,0)); //Save the Session

    } 
}
}
```

The problem I'm having is that `base.Session.Get<CustomType>("MySession")` is always `null`.
Am I missing something on the implementation of sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to save your session using base.SaveSession(). See [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions) near the bottom there is a section title 'Saving in Service'.

```
public class MyAppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public MyAppHost() : base("MyService", typeof(CustomService).Assembly)
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
       Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature()); 
    }
}


public class CustomType : AuthUserSession
{
    public int MyId { get; set; }
}

[Route("/CustomPath")]
public class CustomRequest
{
}

public class CustomResponse
{
}

public class CustomService : Service
{
    public CustomResponse Any(CustomRequest pRequest)
    {
        var CustomSession = base.SessionAs<CustomType>();
        if (CustomSession.MyId == 0)
        {
            CustomSession.MyId = 1; 
            this.SaveSession(CustomSession, new TimeSpan(0,20,0));
        }

        return new CustomResponse();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

There is a Resharper issue with extension methods, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618742/resharper-intellisense-problem-with-extension-methods), which seems to affect SaveSession(). 
**Work Arounds:**

- `ServiceExtensions.SaveSession(this, CustomSession);` ReSharper may prompt to reformat and it will work.
- Ctrl-Alt-space to reformat
- `RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().SaveSession(CustomSession)` can save the
  session.

Comment: I tried that but I got this error: ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service' does not contain a definition for 'SaveSession'   Thanks

Comment: Are you using ReSharper? I updated my answer with some work arounds.

Comment: Yes, I'm using ReSharper, your work around seems to work partially, but when I run the code I got an error when calling SaveSession it says: {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"}. Also, for "sess" I couldn't use a custom type or even a string, instead I'm using AuthUserSession.

Comment: Sorry, 'sess' is just a placeholder for the example...you should replace 'sess' with your CustomSession variable.

Comment: Yes I got that, but after the changes you suggested I still got the error when calling SaveSession: {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"}. Do you have any idea, thanks in advance.

Comment: Now code runs without errors but the session is not saved, I updated my original post, any idea?  thanks

Comment: I updated my example to include all the code I used to save a Session. It uses the MemoryCacheClient so when you stop the server all the cached and session data will be lost.

Comment: I was using JsonServiceClient to test the service, it seems the session doesn't persists with it. Thank you!