# How to access query string param in self hosted app

Tags: servicestack

I have an IIS hosted app which takes an id from query string and instantiates user object like so. In AppHost.Configure I register UserService in IoC like so

```
container.Register(x => new UserService(x.Resolve<IDataContext>()).GetUser()).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```

My UserService (this is not a ServiceStack service, just an internal helper) looks like

```
    public class UserService
    {
        public UserService(IDataContext dataContext)
        {
            _dataContext = dataContext;
        }

        public User GetUser()
        {
            var uid = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["$id$"];
            //snip
        }
        //snip
    }
```

I want to change this to a self hosted app and therefore I don't have access to HttpContext any more. I have looked at HttpListenerContext but nothing seems to be populated when my class is being injected.

Can anyone shed any light on how to pass param from query string to this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access any dependencies in your constructor and every ServiceStack action requires a Request DTO see the [New API wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) for more details.

In your Service actions you can simply access the `base.Request` and `base.Response` when you need them e.g:

```
public class MyService : Service
{
    public UserService UserService { get; set; }

    public User Get(MyRequest request)
    {
        var user = UserService.GetUser(base.Request);
        //snip
    }
    //snip
}
```

Note: there is no singleton for HttpListenerContext for Self-Hosting, so you can't get access to the runtime HTTP Request from inside an IOC lambda.

Comment: I don't think I explained what I'm trying to do well. See my earlier problem here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504130/is-it-possible-to-inject-an-instance-of-object-to-service-at-runtime) UserService is not a ServiceStack action, it is something that gets called by each of my other "real" service stack actions. Basically I want to instantiate a User object without using a plugin as detailed on my other question

Comment: You shouldn't be registering a Service yourself manually. Right, I still probably don't know what you mean, but I've updated my example showing how to get a User from the DataContext.

Comment: I think what was confusing was I was deriving from : Service. I have removed this now and edited my question. I only added it to see if I could access base.Request (which I couldn't as it is null). So hopefully that is clearer. My UserService is not a ServiceStack service, just an internal helper class which I injected in Configure() which would inspect the request, grab the id param and load my User. This worked fine for IIS host but not for self host as I don't have access to HttpContext.

Comment: Right, it's not possible in self-hosting, as there is no equivalent singleton. I've updated an answer with how I'd do it.